# How do I hstack EVERY 50 rows to a long row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

I have a data frame of 300 rows x 6 columns. I want to hstack every 50 rows x 6 columns to 1 row x 300 columns. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this approach:

example data

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['C45','AB','ZU'],['C45','ZO','RE'],
    ['C67','RT','FG',],['C78','TZ','GH']], columns=['id1','id2','id3'])
```

it looks like this:

```
    id1 id2 id3
0   C45 AB  ZU
1   C45 ZO  RE
2   C67 RT  FG
3   C78 TZ  GH
```

command

```
N = 2
pd.concat([df1.iloc[np.arange(i,len(df1),N)].reset_index(drop=True) 
    for i in range(N)], axis=1)
```

the result looks like this:

```
id1 id2 id3 id1 id2 id3
0   C45 AB  ZU  C45 ZO  RE
1   C67 RT  FG  C78 TZ  GH
```

you may also add `rename` after `reset_index` to avoid duplicate column names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to work fine. For my case, to stack every 50 rows, I need to set the '2' in your example to 50, right?

Comment: yes, exactly, I will edit the code to reflect it.

Comment: May I ask how would I rename the new columns? For example, rename them as 1, 2, 3, ...

Comment: Renaming to 1,2,3,... is especially easy, just add argument `ignore_index=True` to `pd.concat` call.